# My images are not formatting properly on my site on load up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I load up my site in whichever browser on first try my images don't seem to align properly unless I resize the browser.

http://sahyogseniorclubmontreal.com/index.html here is a link to my web page .

I seems to happen only when I first open the webpage and is only happening since I uploaded the website to godaddy.  It ws not happening when I was running it local.

```html
<div class="portfolio-list">

  <ul class="nav list-unstyled" id="portfolio-flters">
    <li class="filter filter-active" data-filter=".all">all</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".branding">Parliament Trip</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".mockups">Christmas Supper At Kwality Restaurant</li>
    <!--  <li class="filter" data-filter=".uikits">ui kits</li>
      <li class="filter" data-filter=".webdesign">web design</li>
      <li class="filter" data-filter=".photography">photography</li> -->
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="portfolio-container">

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181121-WA0011.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181121-WA0012.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181122-WA0013.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181122-WA0021.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181122-WA0012.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181123-WA0004.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181122-WA0005.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181121-WA0001.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181121-WA0002.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0001.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0003.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0004.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0005.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0006.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups uikits photography">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0007.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: While reformatting the code I've also added the missing `</div>` tag at the end of snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to set `width` and `height` attributes to your images. Or set them with CSS:

```css
.portfolio-thumbnail img {
  max-width: 200px; /* This is just an example value */
  max-height: 200px; /* Idem */
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-list">

  <ul class="nav list-unstyled" id="portfolio-flters">
    <li class="filter filter-active" data-filter=".all">all</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".branding">Parliament Trip</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".mockups">Christmas Supper At Kwality Restaurant</li>
    <!--  <li class="filter" data-filter=".uikits">ui kits</li>
      <li class="filter" data-filter=".webdesign">web design</li>
      <li class="filter" data-filter=".photography">photography</li> -->
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="portfolio-container">

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181121-WA0011.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181121-WA0012.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181122-WA0013.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181122-WA0021.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181122-WA0012.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181123-WA0004.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181122-WA0005.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181121-WA0001.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all branding">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181121-WA0002.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0001.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0003.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0004.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0005.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0006.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-thumbnail all mockups uikits photography">
    <a class="popup-img" href="images/portfolio/IMG-20181217-WA0007.jpg">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"  alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```